# How to copy data from one already opened excel file (Workbook1,Sheet1,cell A11) to another already opened excel file(workbook2,sheet1,A11)

Tags: vba, excel

I have 2 different opened excel files i want to copy data from first to secound file using macro in the first excel file?

I use this code but it does work when the two Workbooks are opened in 1 excel file
when they are opened in two different excel files it says "Run time error 9" or something like this

```
Sub Macro2()

Macro2 Macro

Range("D5:L5").Select
Selection.Copy
Windows("New_SET_Data.xlsx").Activate
Range("B7").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
    False, Transpose:=True
Windows("Original_SET_Data.xls").Activate

End Sub
```

how to change the code so i will get data from workbook1 in excelfile "A" to workbook2 in excel file "B"

Answer (score 0):

you could use GetInfoFromClosedFile() i guess, but i never tested.

I remember using:

```
dim txt = "'C:\[test.xls]Page 1'!R1C1"
```

this should work in theory...

Comment: what does this mean 'C:\[test.xls]Page 1' is it path of the file?
 and what does !R1C1 mean ?

Comment: Sorry @Foki! Was away for a while! yes the first part is the file path and R1C1 is just a "placeholder" for the real range you want. hope I am clear! but you probably sorted this allready! sorry again!